# Downvote of newcomers with less than 100 points

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

[There](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317780/what-is-the-difference-between-b-and-h-fields?noredirect=1#comment713842_317780) was a small dispute about the downvote of newcomers with less than 110 point:

> ...the SE is supported by only a view enthusiasts. And they are doing this very well. But how to grow up more active people without giving them a chance to adopt to SE? It's really necessary to downvote somebody with less than 100 points?

AccidentalFourierTransform thinks

> ...of course I agree... The question is certainly good and there is no reason to downvote it. It is just a duplicate, but its a good question.

And Countto10 brightens the situation

> ... but it is normal practice either to include some reference you read, but could not follow, or to give your own idea of what the problem involves.

So why not support newcomers and give them a chance to grow up? Why not establish a netquette about this or better not do give the possibility to downvote under zero? Ok, may be it should be possible if someone upvoted the question to downvote it to zero again, but I think this is contraproductive too.

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about downvoting the posts of someone with less than 100 rep (which is not the case in the post you link to), as opposed to allowing users with less than 125 rep the ability to downvote?

Comment: Emilio At the moment I saw the question it has had -1. I upvoted it.

Comment: At the time that question was posted the OP had 400 rep, so I still don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Than it was my mistake

Comment: Have you considered there may be so few senior active users because there are too many rookie users asking "what is the difference  between $\vec H$ and $\vec B$"?

Comment: I don't think most of our long-term and active users are those that start out asking a lot of questions. I myself started out answering, and most of our most active users follow a similar trend of mainly providing answers. If we are doing this for potential long-term active users, then efforts should be focused on answer posts more than question posts. Not that I believe anything really needs to be done at all

Answer (score 6):

The question linked has been closed as a duplicate and was presumably downvoted because it was a duplicate. This has been discussed before in [If a question is duplicate , should it be downvoted?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7665/if-a-question-is-duplicate-should-it-be-downvoted)

Re the broader question of downvoting new members, the voting on a question should be based on the question and only on the question. A bad question posted by a newcomer is still a bad question.

But I do think we are a bit eager to downvote questions. Downvoting bad answers is very important because a wrong or misleading answer has no place on this site, but I consider downvoting questions to be less critical. Beginners to physics sometimes have problems writing a question clearly because they don't understand the terminology we use, and in this case I think we should be sympathetic. Where questions are lazy or a thinly disguised excuse for a polemic I feel less charitable.

Comment: John Downvoted below zero or questions with zero point have nearly the same attention. What I wanted to point out is that the number of active users is very small and to grow up mor  competent unseres you have to give them the chance not to be disillusioned from their first question. Not being a dictator but a pedagogue one has to understand this. ;-)

Comment: @John Rennie : I could not agree more.  It is true that some new users get downvoted but it seems to me that, in most cases, this is entirely justified.  The issue in my mind is not how many new users get downvoted, but how many new users ask reasonably good questions.  Unfortunately the answer is too few: too  many new users ask quick one-off questions about an assignment problem, or ask more senior users to explain some book they are reading without having done any obvious effort at due diligence.  IMO there  is something pedagogical in downvoting bad questions.